# getting error :Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_queried_object() on null in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

i have  hosted my wordpress site to godaddy, i have configured all the things when i open my site, i am getting this error  `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_queried_object() on null in wp-includes/query.php on line 46` , i checked the query.php file, there is inbuilt function

```
function get_query_var( $var, $default = '' ) {
    global $wp_query;   
    return $wp_query->get( $var, $default );
}
```

can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue ?